# Symfony 3 gives me 500 error for no errors

Tags: symfony

I have a fresh install of Symfony 3.4. Whenever i try to reach for "/" it gives me a 500 error. If i append "app_dev.php" to my route (not only "/" route, any route gives me error as of now) it works without any errors. What's the matter?

UPDATE: it seems like it's missing the debug bundle, namely the dump() function. Which is strange because i do have the dump() function, it works perfectly in my twig template. Log says:

```
[2018-11-23 13:04:24] request.CRITICAL: Uncaught PHP Exception
Twig_Error_Syntax: "Did you forget to run "composer require symfony/debug
bundle"? Unknown function "dump" in "index.html.twig"."
```

I run the required command and get this:

```
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.
 Problem 1
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/debug-bundle v4.1.7
    ... all the ay down to 3.4.1
- Installation request for symfony/debug-bundle ^4.1 -> satisfiable by symfony/debug-bundle[v4.1.0, v4.1.1, v4.1.2, v4.1.3, v4.1.4, v4.1.5, v4.1.6, v4.1.7].
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v3.4.0
Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.
```

How can i solve this problem?

Comment: _“What's the matter?”_ - check the error log. That is _always_ the _first thing_ you do on a 500!

Comment: pls check the updated version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default Symfony always runs in production mode. So, to prevent annoying caching and security issues when developing in your app.php in /www folder replace

```
$kernel = new AppKernel('prod', false);
```

with

```
$kernel = new AppKernel('dev', true);
```

Figured it out myself, saved me tons of time.

Comment: That's why we have the app_dev.php File, so that you don't have to do that.

Comment: its because you are using dump in production. Thats not allowed :P